# How to make intellisense treat the current source file as a standalone translation unit

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, intellisense

While refactoring our project sources for future use in other projects, we're encountering a problem: It's getting difficult to identify what really depends of what, because Intellisense magically fixes everything behind the scenes.

Example problem:

- `"c.c"` source file #includes `"a.h"` and then `"b.h"`
- So `"b.h"` should be able to use all `"a.h"` without any `#include` because it is part of the `"c.c"` translation unit
- While editing `"b.h"` Intellisense "correctly" shows all definitions from `"a.h"` which is awesome

But we need a way to make it evident that there is a missing `#include "a.h"` at the top of `"b.h"` for future reusing... Is there any way to make Intellisense treat `"b.h"` as a standalone translation unit?

Edit: Changed the name of the Main source to `"c.c"` for clarification, even if we do have circular includes in our code, it is not the actual problem we need to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of testing you could make a separate translation unit called `test_b_h.c` which only has

```
#include <b.h>
```

As it would not generate any target code it will not have an effect on the size of the resulting executable.

Comment: Such a simple solution and I never figured.. I've just spent hours studing the Visual Studio IDE, but I can do that with a template project and a Python script in minutes...

Comment: @Leonel sometimes the solution is just too obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure having a seperate translation unit is what you want here... #include is very unmagical (it just concatenates the files), and seperate translation units simply compile to seperate object files ("b.h" is unlikely to be a sensible program by itself, as idomatically, headers don't contain anything for which storage is alloted in the object code).

I think what you're looking for is an include guard; try wrapping all of "b.h" in somethng like the following:

```
#ifndef HAVE_B_H
# define HAVE_B_H

/* contents of "b.h" here */

#endif /* HAVE_B_H */
```

This allows you to just include it directly from the top of "a.h" (as well as "a.c"), ensuring it is visible everywhere and not multiply included.
Actually this is good practice in general.

Comment: ```"b.h"``` does have sensible interfaces by itself and allocate resources for different platforms which in turn ```#include``` more generic code from other headers like ```"a.h"```

That's why we're refactoring, to be able to reuse the interfaces and to make them more cross-platform friendly.

We already have guards in every single header.

In the example ```"a.h"``` does not need to include ```"b.h"```, it's ```"b.h"``` the one that shall be put in evidence to include ```"a.h"```